# Laravel Queues Not adding Jobs in Database

Tags: laravel

I have enabled Laravel Queues but the Jobs is not adding inside mine database:

here is the steps what i have follow:

```
php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate
```

in .env file i have changed QUEUE_CONNECTION=database

In mine controller:

```
    CreateCoinImage::dispatch()
                ->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

Do anyone know why the Queues is not working

Comment: I think you have to check the QUEUE_DRIVER and QUEUE_DEFAULT as well.

Answer (score 1):

**.env file you should change queue_driver from sync to database**

```
queue_driver=database
```

**OR**

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

**create queue table in your database with artisan command :**

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
php artisan queue:work
```

Comment: please select this answer if its help for you thank you @user10975763

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use queue:table, make sure your `.env` file has register the queue driver to database

`QUEUE_DRIVER=database`